# SolidJS: How to trigger refetch of createResource?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I have a `createResource` which is working:

```
const fetchJokes = async (programmingOnly) => {
  alert(programmingOnly);
  return (await fetch(`https://official-joke-api.appspot.com/jokes/${programmingOnly?'programming/':''}ten`)).json();
}
//...
const [jokes, { mutate, refetch }] = createResource(programmingOnly(), fetchJokes);
```

Now I want to change the `programmingOnly` boolean via it's signal:

```
const [programmingOnly, setProgrammingOnly] = createSignal(true);
//...
Programming Only: <input type="checkbox" checked={programmingOnly()}
        onInput={()=>{setProgrammingOnly(!programmingOnly());refetch();}}> </input>
```

But this does not work, the alert fires upon subsequent attempts, but with undefined as arg, and nothing happens with the data.

What is the SolidJS way of approaching this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem here is the signal is getting set with false every time. Since `programmingOnly` is a signal it should be accessed as a function to retrieve its value.

Ie..

```
setProgrammingOnly(!programmingOnly)

// should be
setProgrammingOnly(!programmingOnly())
```

You should not need to call refetch or do anything else for the example to work.

Comment: Thanks, my bad there.  It still doesn't update when programmingOnly changes, tho.

Comment: I see on edit you have introduced another bug. You also need to pass the signal not the value to the first argument of createResource:
`createResource(programmingOnly(), fetchJokes)`
should be
`createResource(programmingOnly, fetchJokes)`
Note, this example also toggles between true and false, and false does not fetch.

Comment: Works now.  It's odd that false doesn't trigger, because then a boolean signal doesn't really work with createResource.

Comment: I'm not sure if boolean signal makes sense on its own. If necessary it could be coerced into a string. In any case, this was inspired by Vercel's SWR which has similar behavior with booleans: https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching#conditional